# What is Javascript's version of .NET Standard Class Library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js coming from a .NET background. How can I write classes that implement business logic for me(fetch info from API and returns formatted value for use on front-end) that I can just import simply and keep my Vue projects clean?

Comment: Why does the question have Node tag? Vue is primarily client-side, you won't be able to use Node API in browser. Vue doesn't promote OOP so they shouldn't necessarily be *classes*. For HTTP, there's native Fetch API, Axios is a popular alternative. As for business logic, this is a case for state management, check Vuex.

Answer (score 0):

> What is Javascript's version of .NET Standard Class Library?

The Javascript language itself does not have what most people call a full-blown "standard" library.  The two largest environments where Javascript is used are the browser and node.js and each has their own library that adds functionality on top of the language.  Most of the interfaces added in the browser are "standardized" through the W3C in an effort to make all browsers work the same.  I'm not aware of any standards effort for the node.js libraries.  You can kind of see how it would evolve this way because the browser is purposely limited in what it can do (for security reasons) and thus it doesn't contain rich access to the file system, child processes, TCP stack, creating servers, etc...  Then, along came node.js and it had an objective to be able to do all those things.

So, if you're programming in node.js, then your "standard" are the libraries built-into node.js and documented with it.

If you're fetching http requests from external sources, ironically, the node.js built-in support for that is not great, perhaps because there are so many very good open-source 3rd party libraries for it in NPM (that, I think is what most people use).  You can use the built-in `http.request()` and it works, but it's lower level than most want and not very feature rich when it comes to auth and processing responses and other things like that.

For years, the `request()` library on NPM was about as standard a 3rd party choice as you could get and what was often used in online tutorials and was relied up by many other packages.  But, for a variety of reasons, that has been put into maintenance mode and deprecated for new projects and there are many other good choices such as `got()`, `axios()`, `node-fetch()`, `superagent()` and so on.  You can see a listing of many of the choices [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143).  I personally like `got()`.  It seems simple when you just need something simple, it's ground-up promise-based and can do much more complicated things when required.  Many of the other choices work very well too.

With the huge success of the NPM eco-system for publicly sharing node.js modules, after awhile, many node.js programmers just start thinking of NPM as their available library.  Obviously, you need to understand a little bit of what's behind a module you rely on from NPM (how many other developers are using it, how frequently is it maintained, is it reasonably documented, etc...).  But, if it's a widely used module with a lot of projects using and depending upon it and it seems to be getting regular updates, then the worst thing that happens is that you have to create a fork sometime in the future to fix or add something you want that isn't getting the attention you want.  You always have the source so you're never left high and dry that way.

> How can I write classes that implement business logic for me(fetch info from API and returns formatted value for use on front-end) that I can just import simply and keep my Vue projects clean?

It's not entirely clear exactly what you're asking here.  Yes, you can cleanly write classes that implement business logic that provide data or formatted text for use in the front-end.  But, that answer to that has little to do with "standard" libraries.  You can do all that with non-standard libraries just fine.  You'd just put your classes and their implementation into a module and export the class from the module so you can use it in any other module of your project.  The class implementation details will be hidden in its module.